# Sending email via AJAX - showing progress/status

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 and [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

I have added the following script to my contact form to validate it and send via AJAX (`{{hash_tag}}` in code is Twig variable):

```
<script>


    $("#contactform").validate({
        rules: {
            content_{{ hash_tag }}: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 20
            },
            name_{{ hash_tag }}: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            subject_{{ hash_tag }}: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            email_{{ hash_tag }}: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }

        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(form).attr("action");
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        url : formURL,
                        type: "POST",
                        data : postData,
                        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                        {
                            $('#articlecontent').html(data.content);
                            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                        {
                            $(form).submit();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

</script>
```

The script (after small testing) seems to work. But the problem is - when user have filled in form correctly and when PHP is sending email it may take a few seconds. User after clicking submit button of course doesn't have to know that form is send via AJAX and may think that something is not working ok and may for example click again or do something else.

The question is - how to show user that after clicking something is happening and email will be send in a few seconds? I don't know what's the best practice to do that. Please give me some nice solution. Progress bar is not necessary I think (it's probably hard to determine how long it would take) but maybe some other effect would be fine.

**EDIT**

After changing submitHandler I have now:

```
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(form).attr("action");
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url : formURL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data : postData,
                    beforeSend: function (){
                        $(form).hide();
                        $("#formsending").show();
                    },

                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        $('#articlecontent').html(data.content);
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                    {
                        $(form).submit();
                    },
                    complete: function (){
                        $("#formsending").hide();
                        $(form).show();
                    }

                });
    }
```

It works somehow but still not exactly 100% I wanted. When I click send, form is being hidden and info that email is sending is being displayed but on server-site I have also data validation. Let's assume some complex validation cannot be done by jQuery/HTML5 and it must be done in PHP. When user clicks submit even form is invalid for a small time info that email is being sent is displayed. Is it possible somehow to launch beforeSend (or maybe some similar action) for example after second or 0.5 second to make sure that email is in fact being sent?

Comment: use a loading gif, is universally recongized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice plug in to show a progress wheel whenever an ajax request is in progress.

[jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)

This is especially nice since it will automatically show a progress wheel for any ajax request, so you don't have to specifically set it up everywhere you make ajax calls.

Using this plug in the only code you need to write is

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

**EDIT** (from question update)

If you want to only show the progress spinner when the validation is successful and the email is actually being sent then you could have a separate ajax call that just performs validation and doesn't show any kind of progress (it should not take too long just to validate) and then if that call is successful make a separate ajax call that actually sends the email and does show the spinner.

Example:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(form).attr("action");
        var validateURL = "something else";
        $.ajax({
            url : validateURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                if(data.MyFieldThatIndicatesSuccess) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : formURL,
                        type: "POST",
                        data : postData,
                        beforeSend: function (){
                            $(form).hide();
                            $("#formsending").show();
                        },
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            $('#articlecontent').html(data.content);
                            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                            //handle error
                        }
                        complete: function (){
                            $("#formsending").hide();
                            $(form).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception)
            {
                //handle error
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I've added some more info about solution I've used but still it's not perfect (please look at edited question)

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek What you could do is have a separate ajax call that just validates the data being sent with no progress spinner shown (it shouldn't take long) and then if that is successful submit the ajax call with the progress spinner for actually sending the email.

Comment: Could you give me some sample code how to achieve that in jQuery? I don't know how to add 2 ajax calls that way

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, what you would like is some message or animation to show when the user presses submit and it to go away again once the php has done its thing?

If so you would just have to add some code at the commented areas to show/hide an element that shows a message or a spinner.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(form).attr("action");
        //Some code to make a div appear e.g.
        //$("#contactform").append("<div class='loading'><img src='spinner.gif'></div>");
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url : formURL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data : postData,
                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        //some code to make the div disapear e.g.
                        //$(".loading").remove();
                        $('#articlecontent').html(data.content);
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                    {
                        $(form).submit();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: I've added some more info about solution I've used but still it's not perfect (please look at edited question)